# Image Straightening in iOS using Open CV framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, image-processing

**Code :**

```
cv::Point2f src_vertices[4]; 
src_vertices[0] = c1[0]; 
src_vertices[1] = c1[1]; 
src_vertices[2] = c1[2]; 
src_vertices[3] = c1[3]; 

cv::Point2f dst_vertices[4]; 
dst_vertices[0] = c2[0]; 
dst_vertices[1] = c2[1]; 
dst_vertices[2] = c2[2]; 
dst_vertices[3] = c2[3]; 

cv::Mat warpMatrix = getPerspectiveTransform(src_vertices,dst_vertices); 

cv::Mat output = cv::Mat::zeros(original.cols,original.rows , CV_32FC3); 

cv::warpPerspective(original, output, warpMatrix,cv::Size(606,606));

 UIImage *_adjustedImage = [MAOpenCV UIImageFromCVMat:output];
```

**Below is the original image**
[image]

**After apply straightening, output is below image**

[image: http://imgur.com/6Ycodof]

**Issue**

The output of the image that we are getting after straightening is getting cropped a bit from the corner and the output comes from the Open CV framework itself.

How to resolved this issue. Please let me know if anybody has found the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Transform/warp it to a destination that is big enough to hold the full image

Comment: I think some one could help, if you share the code and techniques what you have tried.

Comment: @2vision2: Below is my code.

Comment: cv::Point2f src_vertices[4];
src_vertices[0] = c1[0];  src_vertices[1] = c1[1];  src_vertices[2] = c1[2];    src_vertices[3] = c1[3];
    
    cv::Point2f dst_vertices[4];
    dst_vertices[0] = c2[0];  dst_vertices[1] = c2[1];  dst_vertices[2] = c2[2];    dst_vertices[3] = c2[3];
    
    cv::Mat warpMatrix = getPerspectiveTransform(src_vertices,dst_vertices);
    cv::Mat output = cv::Mat::zeros(original.cols,original.rows , CV_32FC3);;
    cv::warpPerspective(original, output, warpMatrix,cv::Size(606,606));
    
    UIImage *_adjustedImage = [MAOpenCV UIImageFromCVMat:output];

Comment: @Raxit Please modify the question this way 1) post your code 2) input and output of the code 3) Expected output / Issue you are facing.

Comment: @2vision2: Thanks for suggestion. Did you able to find any missing points in above code.

Comment: Nope i couldnt find anything.. Sorry

Comment: @Micka: I have used getPerspectiveTransform method. Did you find any problem in above code ?

Comment: instead of `cv::Size(606,606)` you have to compute the warped size before warping and use that. In addition, you might need to modify your `warpMatrix` by a translation term to move the warped image within the destination image. To find the needed size of your destination image, warp/transform the corner points of your source image border and compute the bounding rect of that warped corners. The translation term must be chosen the way that the topmost point will be on y coordinate zero and the leftmost point will be on x coordinate zero.

Comment: @2vision2: Not getting expected output. Thanks for concern

Comment: As Micka said, the problem is with the height of the output image. Do you got that point? I think the height of the output image should be equal to height of the original image + amount of warping done. Just a point and I am not sure!

Comment: @2vision2: We are straightening the part of image without creating any new layer or image of that part. so straightening is applied on original image. Because this point, we are not able to show it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question is asked quite often, I've written a few lines of code which save some time for many others.

try this:

```
cv::Rect computeWarpedContourRegion(const std::vector<cv::Point> & points, const cv::Mat & homography)
{
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> transformed_points(points.size());

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<points.size(); ++i)
    {
        // warp the points
        transformed_points[i].x = points[i].x * homography.at<double>(0,0) + points[i].y * homography.at<double>(0,1) + homography.at<double>(0,2) ;
        transformed_points[i].y = points[i].x * homography.at<double>(1,0) + points[i].y * homography.at<double>(1,1) + homography.at<double>(1,2) ;
    }

    // dehomogenization necessary?
    if(homography.rows == 3)
    {
        float homog_comp;
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<transformed_points.size(); ++i)
        {
            homog_comp = points[i].x * homography.at<double>(2,0) + points[i].y * homography.at<double>(2,1) + homography.at<double>(2,2) ;
            transformed_points[i].x /= homog_comp;
            transformed_points[i].y /= homog_comp;
        }
    }

    // now find the bounding box for these points:
    cv::Rect boundingBox = cv::boundingRect(transformed_points);
    return boundingBox;
}

cv::Rect computeWarpedImageRegion(const cv::Mat & image, const cv::Mat & homography)
{
    std::vector<cv::Point> imageBorder;
    imageBorder.push_back(cv::Point(0,0));
    imageBorder.push_back(cv::Point(image.cols,0));
    imageBorder.push_back(cv::Point(image.cols,image.rows));
    imageBorder.push_back(cv::Point(0,image.rows));

    return computeWarpedContourRegion(imageBorder, homography);
}

cv::Mat adjustHomography(const cv::Rect & transformedRegion, const cv::Mat & homography)
{
    if(homography.rows == 2) throw("homography adjustement for affine matrix not implemented yet");

    // unit matrix
    cv::Mat correctionHomography = cv::Mat::eye(3,3,CV_64F);
    // correction translation
    correctionHomography.at<double>(0,2) = -transformedRegion.x;
    correctionHomography.at<double>(1,2) = -transformedRegion.y;


    return correctionHomography * homography;
}

int main()
{
    // straightening algorithm without cropping:
    cv::Mat original = cv::imread("straightening_src.png");
    cv::Mat output;


    cv::Point2f src_vertices[4];
    cv::Point2f dst_vertices[4];
    // I have to add them manually, you can just use your old code here.
    // my result will look different, since I don't use your original point correspondences, but system is the same...
    src_vertices[0] = cv::Point2f(108,190);
    src_vertices[1] = cv::Point2f(273,178);
    src_vertices[2] = cv::Point2f(389,322);
    src_vertices[3] = cv::Point2f(183,355);

    dst_vertices[0] = cv::Point2f(172,190);
    dst_vertices[1] = cv::Point2f(374,193);
    dst_vertices[2] = cv::Point2f(380,362);
    dst_vertices[3] = cv::Point2f(171,366);

    // compute homography
    cv::Mat warpMatrix = getPerspectiveTransform(src_vertices,dst_vertices);

    // now you have to find out, whether the warped image will fit to the output image or whether it will be cropped.
    // if it will be cropped you will most probably have to
    // 1. find out how big your output image must be and the coordinates it will be warped to.
    // 2. modify your transformation (by a translation) so that the output image will be placed properly inside the output image

    // part 1: find the region that will hold the new image.
    cv::Rect warpedImageRegion = computeWarpedImageRegion(original, warpMatrix);

    // part 2: modify the transformation.
    cv::Mat adjustedHomography = adjustHomography(warpedImageRegion, warpMatrix);

    cv::Size transformedImageSize = cv::Size(warpedImageRegion.width,warpedImageRegion.height);
    cv::warpPerspective(original, output, adjustedHomography, transformedImageSize);

    cv::imshow("output", output);
    cv::imwrite("straightening_result.png", output);
    cv::waitKey(-1);

}
```

for this input (1) and the given transformation correspondences you will get that result (2)

(1)

[image]

(2)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for putting the efforts. Let me try to integrate in my code. Once it is done. i will update you.

Comment: It is working. Finally got the expected result. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

After the image is skewed, it should be possible to remove the black extra part of the image.